# Java API for type-safe, typeclass based Scala map?

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, type-safety

We are using something like the following Scala code to implement a type-safe map of keys and values. Instances of this map are sent as actor messages and stored in Redis and HornetQ, etc. Now we have a new requirement that we need to provide a Java(8) API. This is fairly tricky, due to the differences between Java and Scala types and the fact that when making calls from Java to Scala you don't get help from the Scala compiler. Here is the basic type-safe key and map definition in Scala:

```scala
abstract case class Key(name: String) extends Serializable {
    type Value
}

object Key {
    type Aux[A] = Key { type Value = A }

    def create[A](name: String): Key.Aux[A] = new Key(name) {
        type Value = A
    }
}
case class TypeSafeMap(data: Map[Key, Any] = Map.empty) extends Serializable {
    def get[A](key: Key): Option[key.Value] = 
        data.get(key).asInstanceOf[Option[key.Value]]

    def set[A](key: Key.Aux[A], value: A): TypeSafeMap = 
        TypeSafeMap(data + (key → value))
}
```

Usage:

```scala
val myKey1 = Key.create[Double]("myKey1")
val myKey2 = Key.create[Int]("myKey2")
val myKey3 = Key.create[String]("myKey3")
val myMap = TypeSafeMap()
    .set(myKey1, 12.3)
    .set(myKey2, 42)
    .set(myKey3, "hello")
```

The above code is not Java compatible as is. We could add a method
like this for Java use, but it would throw away all the type-safety:

```scala
final def jset(key: Key, value: Any): TypeSafeMap = {
  TypeSafeMap(data + (key → value))
}
```

Another option would be to use generic types that are more compatible with Java:

```scala
case class Key[A](name: String, typ: Class[A]) extends Serializable {
    override def toString = name
}

object Key {
    def create[A](name: String, typ: Class[A]): Key[A] = 
        new Key[A](name, typ)
}

case class TypeSafeMap(data: Map[Key[_], Any] = Map.empty) extends Serializable {
    def get[A](key: Key[A]): Option[A] = 
        data.get(key).asInstanceOf[Option[A]]

    def set[A](key: Key[A], value: A): TypeSafeMap = 
        TypeSafeMap(data + (key → value))
}
```

This kind of works for Scala and Java, but restricts you to types that have a Class object, which I think rules out arrays and collections as value types.
I guess the work-around would be to require wrapper classes in these cases.

Another issue is primitive types: If a Key's value type is defined as Scala Int, it will not match a java.lang.Integer, for example.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.